# How to boot Linux on Samsung r425 laptop?

Tags: linux, boot, laptop

I've tried different distributions and kernel versions. It boots normally from a flash drive and CD, but hangs almost immediately after I select Linux in GRUB when booting from the hard drive.

fstab:

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system>     <dir>    <type>     <options>                 <dump>  <pass>
# UUID=0fa7978a-cdc8-4320-a0a5-93b2e77a15fa
/dev/sda5           /         ext4      rw,relatime,data=ordered  0       2
```

grub.cfg: http://pastebin.com/KerD8BLe

Comment: post us the content of your grub and your fstab present on the HDD installation please

Comment: @Znau, added grub.cfg and fstab to question

Comment: i meant the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

Comment: @Znau, I use grub2. List of operating systems is in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: added an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Pick the line in grub making refference for your linux menu entry and change the value after the comma to "5", as your linux OS is booting from sda5. should look something like

```
   menuentry "Linux" {
insmod ufs2
set root=(hd1,1)
chainloader +1
}
```

so in your case, it would be    root = (**hd0,5**)

Comment: it is GRUB2. grub.cfg is generated by script. There is `set root='hd0,msdos5'` for each linux entry. It finds and starts booting kernel but freezes on some point.